# Send notification for group of users in firebase by REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I'm trying to send notification of list of users, is this applicable in firebase REST API.
what I tried and succeeded is send a notification for a specific user and broadcast notification but I didn't find a sample request for a group of users!

below is the request I used for Broadcast by POSTMAN :

URL :

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Body:

```
{ "data": 
{
 "title": "Firebase notification",
 "detail": "I am firebase notification. you can customise me. enjoy"
 },
 "notification":{
      "title":"Hi from Postman ",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
 "to":"/topics/all"
// I don't think to could accept an array of the users device token 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Message doesn't have the concept of a user, nor of a group of users. It instead has two ways to target messages:

1. You can send messages to [one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices) or [more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices) FCM tokens, which is a token each installation of the app generates. By sending messages to tokens, the sender determines who they send the message to.
2. You can [send messages to topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics), which app instances subscribe to. By sending messages to topics, the **subscriber** can determine which messages they receive.

Neither of these is pertinently better than the other, as they both have their own use-cases. The choice is typically one of convenience versus control.

- If you send the message to a topic, you have to assume that all your users can receive the message (as they are the ones subscribing to topics).
- If you want full control over who receives the message, you should keep a list of FCM tokens on your server, and pass the tokens to deliver the message into the API call.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, that I what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase provides the Rest API for push notifications. This is the base URL `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

If we need to send notifications for multiple devices at a time then we need to pass this JSON body inside the POST request.

```
{
  'data': {
    'title': 'New Message',
    'message': 'You have a new message',
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2'
  },
  'notification': {
    'title': 'Your Notification Title',
    'body': 'Your Notification Message Body',
    'android_channel_id': 'channel_id_for_receive_notification',
    'mutable_content': true,
    'sound': 'Tri-tone'
  },
  'registration_ids': ["token1", "token2", "token3", ...as needed ]  
  
},
```

Here, the `data` object contains custom key-value pairs that can be used to customize the message. The `notification` object contains the title and body of the message. The `registration_ids` array contains the device tokens of the target audience.